# Is there a way to mix codes targetting device with different compute capabilities together in a single DLL?

Tags: dll, cuda, gpu, nvidia

For example, if I write a CUDA library, there are some functions that used some exclusive SM 3.X features (for instance, shuffle intrinsics).

Whilst other functions use only  SM 2.X features.

I want to compiled all these lib functions into a single DLL and let the DLL select the appropriate functions at runtime, is that possible in CUDA?

Like:

```
static __global__ void Kernel_SM2x(void)
//...
static __global__ void Kernel_SM3x(void)
//...
```

With an entry function in the DLL, based on hardware feature test, launch suitable kernels/routines.

Comment: To some degree, the CUDA fatbin model has this feature baked into it already. Could you maybe expand your question with a simple usage case? Are you meaning to have many instances of a particular function which is compiled into a number of architecture specific versions, or just a collection of different functions which are architecture specific?

Comment: @talonmies: just a collections of different functions (static) that targetting different architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have same points of entries (e.g. kernel names, launch parameters, arguments are same) then you can rely on precompiler (this is from grabCut CUDA SDK sample):

```
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ < 200
        unsigned int gmm_flags_bvec = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<32; ++i)
        {
            if (gmm_flags[i] > 0)
            {
                gmm_flags_bvec |= 1 << i;
            }
        }
        tile_gmms[blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x] = gmm_flags_bvec;
#else
        tile_gmms[blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x] = __ballot(gmm_flags[threadIdx.x] > 0);
#endif
```

then you would have to pass several -gencode arguments to NVCC - and it will build different kernels and include them in your executable. Driver will automatically pick the proper kernel for your device when application is running.

Then, if your host code differs between different device architectures (e.g. you do less on the device if it is really old) you can create several CU for different compute capabilities  - and have every CU file will export host function that would serve as an entry point. It will be your application responsibility to use proper entry point depending on available hardware.

E.g. you would have application_logic_sm3x.cu that contains kernels that use SM 3.x features and a regular C function called compute_sm3x(...). Application_logic_sm2x.cu will use SM 2.x features and a contain C function called compute_sm2x(...).

Your main.cpp function will use cudaGetDeviceProperties and then call either compute_sm3x or  compute_sm2x depending on available hardware.

**Update** You can take a look at simplePrintf sample from CUDA Toolkit 5.0 - it has slightly different code paths for 1.x and 2.x and newer.